# Can't search for any applications from the Windows Start Screen

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

I always used to be able to hit Windows key on my keyboard, have the Windows Start menu pop up, and then start typing an applications name and the application would pop up and I could run it.  Now when I try this Windows just jumps back to my desktop.

Can anyone tell me what might be going on here?

Comment: Windows Key is working here - Windows 10 and 11.  Try the initial OS repair: ......  (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: Please let us know if DISM / SFC resolved the issue.  There are more in-depth repairs

Comment: Could be windows search is not working, or the database needs to be reinitialised. Also, I believe Microsoft is phasing out Cortana, so this may be a bug after windows update.